# document found some problems

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are sorry, We cant open xxx.docx because we found a problem with its contents but i aint some problem with my document i can open it on my desktop?

```
 using (SPWeb web = mysites.RootWeb)
 {
     using (mysites.OpenWeb())
     {
         SPList list = web.Lists["myList"];

         string file = fileName;

         Stream fStream = File.OpenRead(file);
         var byteArray = new byte[fStream.Length];
         string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
         fStream.Close();
         if (filename != null)
         {
             string fileUrl = list.RootFolder.Url + "/" + filename;
             SPFile fileSp = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, byteArray, true);
             SPListItem item = fileSp.Item;
             item["Name"] = fileSp.Name;

             item.Update();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill the byte array

```
using (SPWeb web = mysites.RootWeb)
{
 using (mysites.OpenWeb())
 {
     SPList list = web.Lists["myList"];

     string file = fileName;

     Stream fStream = File.OpenRead(file);
     var byteArray = new byte[fStream.Length];
     fStream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fStream.Length));
     string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
     fStream.Close();
     if (filename != null)
     {
         string fileUrl = list.RootFolder.Url + "/" + filename;
         SPFile fileSp = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, byteArray, true);
         SPListItem item = fileSp.Item;
         item["Name"] = fileSp.Name;

         item.Update();
     }
 }
}
```